# CUDA-C importing bitmap image

Tags: c, cuda, bitmap

Now, I have my simple project on changing the color image into white&black image using CUDA-C.

But I got a problem with importing/loading a bitmap image into program. I don't know how to import it.

So...

1. CUDA-C have a specific function about importing/loading bitmap image?
2. If yes, what is it and how to use it?
3. If no, how do you do with importing/loading bitmap image?

Thank you.

Comment: There is ample documentation for CUDA. A scan of the table of contents of the API reference would take 30 seconds and answer both (1) and (2).

Comment: I just looked through the Cuda documentation and there is mention of opengl implementation which hardly implies the possibility of importing images into CUDA kernels. To a beginner they will have no idea why OpenGL is important at all. Nonetheless there are no examples listed on the documentation other than the hard to find samples provided by Robert. Up voted question because you did not list a link showing evidence of such documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There's really nothing that is CUDA-specific about loading a bitmap image into an application.
If you have a preferred method for loading a bitmap image into an application, you should be able to use it with a CUDA app.  You will obviously be loading the image into the host application space first.  After that, if you want to transfer it to the device, you can use any of the standard methods for transferring data to the device to accomplish this.

1. CUDA (i.e. the runtime API) doesn't have any specific functions for importing/loading a bitmap image
2. -
3. There are many ways to load an image.  If you are already using OpenGL or DirectX, then you will want to use a method associated with one of those APIs, and then use the [appropriate interop API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html) within CUDA to manipulate the object.

If you want to import a bitmap image directly into a CUDA program without using a graphics API, take a look at the [CUDA samples](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html), as a number of them do this and provide helper functions that you may want to re-use.

For example, the [dct8x8 sample](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#dct8x8) provides a file called `BmpUtil.cpp` which contains a number of useful bitmap import/handling routines, and the dct8x8 app (`dct8x8.cu`) shows how these may be used directly in a CUDA app.